# How to change emulate Android Upgrade

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-version

Is it possible to emulate that the user upgrades the Android version?

My app breaks when the user upgrades from Jelly Bean to KitKat. I think I fixed the issue, but I don't know how to test it.

I've tried to create an emulator running 4.3 and then "upgrade" it to 4.4 by changing the following properties in the avd-configuration

```
~/.android/<avd>.ini: target
~/.android/<avd>/config.ini: image.sysdir.1
~/.android/<avd>/hardware-qemu.ini: kernel.path, disk.ramdisk.path, disk.systemPartition.initPath
```

but it only results in a emulator that can't start.

Comment: Previously I used a hack to get the path to the sd-card. It did pretty much the same as the new method getExternalFilesDirs() in KitKat. However when the path I found with my hack is accessed in KitKat it throws a access denied exception due to a much stricter permission model.

Comment: And why do you need to emulate OS update? Why can't you just test the app agains different Android versions?